# Why does font-size: 1em; *increase* the size of <button> content?

Tags: html, css

Given the following example, I was surprised to find that adding `font-size: 1em` to a `<button>` element causes the size of the content to *increase*

[example on codepen: "button font-size 1em increases?"](https://codepen.io/ChaseMoskal/pen/pBaMma)

```html
<p>normal</p>
<p style="font-size: 1em;">normal</p>

<button>normal</button>
<button style="font-size: 1em;">big?</button>
```

I was expecting the two buttons to be the same size, like the paragraphs. Why is one button bigger than the other?

Answer (score 6):

The default style for the given element in Chrome contains the following:

```css
font: 400 11px system-ui;
```

Most other browsers have something similar, details left to the reader.

By setting the font-size to `1em`, you're setting it to the default font-size inherited from the parent, or if none exist, your browser settings, which by default is `16px`.

Comment: Yes. Pedantic side note: in HTML, a button always has a parent; it's not possible that no parent exists.